# Java double to SQL Server data type

Tags: java, sql-server, liquibase

I want to insert some Java Double values some columns from a table(I am using SQL Server).
How can I create the aforementioned table using Liquibase? More exact, what type should the column be? The attempt below is not working. Apparently Float is not precise enough for that.

```
<column name="visitsAvg" type="FLOAT"/>
```

Comment: It is not working how? Do you get an error, if so what is it? If not, how is it not working? Have you tried using type `DOUBLE`?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am using Spring Batch and get an exception with the message `The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I got NaN instead of a number. More exactly, at some point in my code there was a division by 0. Hence, the issue was not with converting Java Double to some SQL type, nor with Liquibase. I have wrongly assumed that the problem might lie there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Liquibase uses the JDBC types for columns. The JDBC/SQL type `FLOAT` is not the same as the SQL Server type `FLOAT`. The JDBC type `FLOAT` is a 32 bit single precision floating point. You should specify `DOUBLE` if you want 64 bit double precision (`FLOAT(53)` in SQL Server).

Likely liquibase translates the request for `type="FLOAT"` to a column of type `FLOAT(24)` in SQL Server, which is insufficient to store a Java `double` with full precision.

Comment: I have specified DOUBLE, but I still get the same problem. I have even tried java.sql.Types.DOUBLE, but with no improvement. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Dragos I think you need to show some actual code that triggers the error and the actual table definition in SQL server